# How to add webp support to pillow on android=

Tags: python, android, kivy, webp

I am trying to make an app that works with webp files and converts them to png. The problem is that it seems to me that the Pillow recipe for python4android does not add webp support. How can I get the web support added with the recipe?

Answer (score 0):

The two steps are:

1. work out how webp support should be enabled
2. modify the python-for-android pillow recipe to do that when building for Android

For instance, if this requires setting a compile argument, that argument would need to be added to the recipe's compile command.

Comment: I only have to change the recipe or also the patches file? I just tried to do that, but I still don't get it. I don't quite understand how to add it. Should I add the instructions for you to download and compile libwebp from the libwebp repository? I thought I should create a recipe to download and compile libwebp.

Comment: On linux you have to install libwebp. I guess I should add it on android, I guess pillow looks for the libwebp.so but they don't exist on android.  The problem is that I don't know if I should add it to the pillow recipe or if I need to create a recipe for you to download and compile libwebp. I also don't know the right way to do it from python. The linux terminal uses ./autogen.sh and then /configure to later use make. But in this case I don't know how to do it. Could you give me some link to see how to do it? There's not that much information in the p4a documentation. Thank you

Comment: If libwebp is the required dependency, then yes it also needs a recipe. I'm afraid I don't have any documentation other than the existing recipes.